# Retrieve multiple value from HTML input and store in JSON key, value[Array]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, maps

Good evening all!

I am currently working with google maps api.
The google maps asks for a json format to set directions.

Everything works fine if i make my own json object, but i would like to retrieve data from input fields and store it in the json object.

Right now i can retrieve 1 value from the input field and store it. But i woud like to retrieve multiple values. This is needed to set an direction on the maps. I need to find a way to store the multiple values in an json object as array. Correct my if i wrote some things wrong, i am not a expert :)

"key" : "Array"

See below for the example + Code

This is what i need to try to get: 
A user comes to the page and sees 2 input fields, he fills in Amsterdam and Rome but he always needs Paris. So the user press the + icon. Another input field appears and he fills in Paris. when the user submits this below must be the json result from the input fields

```
"locatie" : ["Berlin", "Amsterdam", "Paris", "Rome"]
```

This is is my form:

```
<form onsubmit="return make_json(this);">
  Locatie:  <input type="text" name="locatie">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Make Trip">
</form>
```

My js function:

```
function make_json(form) {
    var json = {

      "locatie" : form.locatie.value

      // this is what works and what i would like to retrieve from multiple input fields
      //"locatie" : ["Paris", "Amsterdam"]
    };
    return json;
  }
```

In the google maps api i call the function and use the json:

```
var jsonArray = make_json();
```

Comment: How do you input them? Separated by spaces?

Comment: i don't put them in separated, i can only fill in one location, i need to find a way to add multiple locations. So when someone wants to add another location they press the + icon. Another input field appears and they can add another location and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an array and `push` the values to it when the button is clicked.

```js
// Declare location array
var locations = [];

// Button bindings
var locationButton = document.getElementById("addNewLocation");
locationButton.onclick = addNewLocation;

var displayJsonButton = document.getElementById("displayJsonObject");
displayJsonButton.onclick = displayJsonObject;

// Button functions
function addNewLocation() {
  var location = document.getElementById("locationText").value;
  locations.push(location);
  document.getElementById("locationText").value = "";
}

function makeJsonObject() {
  var json = {
     location : locations
  }
  
  return json;
}

function displayJsonObject() {
  var obj = makeJsonObject();
  console.log(obj.location);
}
```

```html
<input id="locationText" type="text" />
<button id="addNewLocation">Add</button>
<button id="displayJsonObject">Display JSON</button>
```

The results will be populated in the console.   I have also returned the JSON object for you in the `displayJsonObject()` function, which you could use to pass to the API.

Comment: @Marc - no problem, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, if you want to keep showing the locations entered before adding new location.

```js
function addInput() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("name", "locatie[]");
  inputs.appendChild(input);
}

function make_json() {
  var form = document.querySelector("form");
  var values = [];
  var locations = form['locatie[]'];
  if (locations.length) {
    locations.forEach(function(input) {
      values.push(input.value);
    });
  } else {
    values.push(locations.value);
  }
  var json = {
    "locatie": values
  };
  console.log(json);
  return json;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Locatie:
  <div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="locatie[]">
  </div>
  <button onClick="addInput()">+</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Make Trip" onClick="make_json(this)">
</form>
```

**Note:** Take care of UI. If user enters more number of inputs, UI may deform.